# Разрезать на части Bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, bitmap

Цель такова: Разделить MovieClip на 8 частей(Пока хотя бы на две).
Для этого перегоняю MovieClip в BitmapData  и там пытаюсь отделить кусок 10х10 пикселей.
Компилятор не ругается, но и картинка не обрезается. Почему не работает, понять не могу.

Код:

```
var tempData:BitmapData = cropBitmap(new BitmapData(gameArray[i][j].width, gameArray[i][j].height, false, 0xffffff), 10, 10, 0, 0);

var tempBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(tempData);
tempData.draw(gameArray[i][j]);
gameArray[i][j].addChild(tempBitmap);
```

Код функции `cropBitmap`

```
private function cropBitmap(bmd:BitmapData, newWidth:uint, newHeight:uint, newX:uint=0, newY:uint=0):BitmapData
    {
        var newBMD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(newWidth, newHeight);
        for(var i = 0; i < newHeight; i++)
            for(var j = 0; j < newWidth; j++)
                newBMD.setPixel(j,i,bmd.getPixel(j+newX,i+newY));

        return newBMD;
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте методы BitmapData copyPixels() или draw().

Comment: newBMD.copyPixels(bmd, new Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200), new Point(100, 100));

всегда копирует данные с верхнего левого угла, т.е. с координат (0, 0), как исправить?

Comment: у меня работает не с верхнего угла а так как указано 100*100:

    new Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200),

Comment: @ShockWave, а в `new Point(100, 100)` неважно, что указывать?

Comment: как это неважно? вы читали документацию по методу?
это целевая точка, куда копируется указанный прямоугольник
http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()

Comment: Я так и понял, но дело в том, что у меня изменение этой точки ничего не меняет, хоть 0 поставь, хоть 200

Comment: значит что то упущено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед добавлением надо было очистить MovieClip

```
while (gameArray[i][j].numChildren)
    gameArray[i][j].removeChildAt(0);
```